# C++ Out of Bounds Error

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, vector

I am trying to push a certain struct that exists in my private class into a vector of the class type records. I get the variable data in my main function but for some reason I keep getting an out of bounds error when trying to copy the information into the struct. If you could explain the error in my method of pushing the struct into the class vector that would be great... I included my planned print function as well.

Here's the class :

```
class students
{
public:
    // All necessary member functions here
    students(int RUID, string first_name, string last_name, vector<double> quiz_grades, array<double, 3> exam_grades)
    {
        record records;
        records.RUID = RUID;
        records.first_name = first_name;
        records.last_name = last_name;


        for (int i = 0; i < quiz_grades.size(); ++i)
        {
            records.quiz_grades[i] = quiz_grades[i];
        }


        for (int i = 0; 0 < 3; ++i)
        {
            records.exam_grades[i] = exam_grades[i];
        }

        student_records.push_back(records);
    }


    void printRecords()
    {
        //vector<record>::iterator it = student_records.begin(); it != student_records.end(); ++it
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < student_records.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << "Ruid: " << student_records[i].RUID << endl;
            cout << "First Name: " << student_records[i].first_name << endl;
            cout << "Last Name: " << student_records[i].last_name << endl;
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < student_records[i].quiz_grades.size(); ++j)
            {
                cout << "Quiz grade " << j + 1 << " is: " << student_records[i].quiz_grades[j] << endl;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                cout << "Test grade " << k + 1 << " is: " << student_records[i].exam_grades[k] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    // using the friend function in class 
    friend void change_name(students stdn); // passing all necessary inputs 

private:
    struct record
    {
        int RUID;
        string first_name;
        string last_name;
        vector<double> quiz_grades;
        array<double, 3> exam_grades = { 0,0,0 };
    };
    vector<record> student_records;
};
```

Here's my main function:

```
int main()
{
    string input;
    bool quit = false;
    int RUID;
    string first;
    string last;
    double grade = 100;

    vector<double> quizG;
    array <double, 3> examG = { 0, 0, 0 };

    cout << " --'new' to add, 'quit' to end--" << endl;

    while (quit != true)
    {

        cout << "Please enter would you would like to do: ";
        cin >> input;
        cout << endl;


        if (input == "quit")
        {
            quit = true;
            break;
        }

        if (input == "new")
        {
            cout << "Please enter the RUID: ";
            cin >> RUID;
            cout << endl << "Please enter the first name: ";
            cin >> first;
            cout << endl << "Please enter the last name: ";
            cin >> last;
            cout << "Enter quiz grades. Enter number less than 0 to stop." << endl;
            while (grade >= 0)
            {
                cout << "Enter quiz grade: ";
                cin >> grade;
                if (grade >= 0)
                {
                    quizG.push_back(grade);
                }
                else if (grade < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                cout << "Please enter " << i + 1 << " test grade: ";
                cin >> grade;
                examG[i] = grade;
            }
        }
        students stdn(RUID, first, last, quizG, examG);
        //stdn.printRecords();
    }



    //  change_name(stdn);

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

In `students::students()`,

```
for (int i = 0; 0 < 3; ++i)
           //  ^^^ should be `i`
```

is obviously wrong.

Comment: that clearly addresses my issue with the array; however I still get the out of range issue with the vector.

Comment: @Djrover `records.quiz_grades[i] = quiz_grades[i];` should be `records.push_back (quiz_grades[i]);` because `records.quiz_grades` contain no elements (size = 0), since it was created just moments ago, and still, is empty, and you are trying to access (non-existant) elements from it.